# Ember Model correct way Post and Comments Async

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a initial page where shows all posts.
Post as many comments, but in this initial page I don't wanna show comments. When User click in a post, the application goes to url posts/post/1  in this page I wanna show the comments of post.

My server has this endpoint

**My server should provide separates endpoints for /posts and /comments or posts/:id/comments/ ?**

**what/how is the right way to fetch(fetch or find)?**

Model

```
// Post
export default DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment'),
});

// Comment
export default DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be for your server to return the comments along with the post - called "sideloading".

So, if you called a GET on /post/1 and that post had comments 1,2, and 3, the JSON returned would include the "post" as well as those three comments

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to that URL "posts/post/1" you can get the dynamic segment value i.e 1 in your case.
In your model hook (in post route) find comment with that dynamic segment value
Eg:

```
 model: function() {
    return this.store.find("comments", post_id);
}
```

In your controller you can access this model by 
    `var temp = this.get('model');`

Comment: & @millerbr
and how about comments? It's possible fetch posts without comments field and after route comments fetch all comments & relations ?